# How to format time in client get from pallet_timestamp polkadotjs?

Tags: polkadot-js, date

I get 1,660,103,328,001 type string from substrate node created by T::Timestamp::now(). What type is this? How can I format this value to readable date time? I've tried with new Date() but it return a time around 1953 in console and invalid date in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T::Timestamp::now()` return type `Duration`. But we usually convert into `u64`

You can not check in PolkadotJs, PolkadotJs only return timestamp
You can check unix timestamp conversion: https://www.epochconverter.com/

In Reactjs code, you can render like this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

```
                  <Your Tag>
                    {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
                      year: 'numeric',
                      month: '2-digit',
                      day: '2-digit',
                      hour: '2-digit',
                      minute: '2-digit',
                      second: '2-digit',
                    }).format(<your query timestamp>)}
                  </Your tag>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it return "RangeError: date value is not finite in DateTimeFormat format()". I've tried some solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing change

Comment: `const timestamp = 1607110465663`

`const date = new Date(timestamp);`

Maybe your timestamp should be `u64` not `string`
And replace `<your query timestamp>` by `date`

Comment: You can try this: `<your query timestamp>` is `number` not `string`. It's working

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp.now is miliseconds since unix epoch. To convert you can use the normal JS Date.

```js
/* retrieve the timestamp */
const now = await api.query.timestamp.now()

/* get the ms as a JS number */
const ms = now.toNumber()

/* create a JS Date */
const dt = new Date(ms)

/* print the date to the console - current locale */
console.log(dt.toLocaleString())
```